# Datatables TableTools stopped working with missing file

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables

Setting up the jQuery-datatables-rails gem gave me a error message with a missing file with this gem and installing bootstrap3 data tables:

`gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', git: 'git://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails.git'`

`Sprockets::FileNotFound in Posts#index`

`//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables` is missing

Am I doing something wrong on install or what has changed?

-R

Answer (score 0):

try to use https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails (follow "General Installation" guide and do not use master version from git)

Comment: Already did unfortunately.  Kept getting the error for: ```//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables```